# Don't show any record given a condition (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Good morning, I am trying to perform the following query in MySQL:
Show the name and surname of the consultants who have not participated in any "Juan Perez" project.
I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT consultant.name, consultant.surname FROM consultor
INNER JOIN participate ON participate.id_consultant = consultant.id
INNER JOIN project ON  project.id = participate.id_project
INNER JOIN cliente ON  client.id = project.id_client
WHERE client.name NOT IN("Juan Perez")
```

But when I execute the query, it only hides those that are directly related in the tables.
How could I hide the other records where the consultants appear so that they do not appear?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try using Left JOIN instead of Inner join.

Comment: Are you able to give us some example data showing the tables and the data you’re getting that you don’t want

Comment: @Aurelian I think I did not explain myself well, the idea is that if the consultant "Sofia" participates in a project for the client "Juan" and in another for the client "Pedro", do not show "Sofia", but "Camila" only participates in the project of "Pedro" if he shows it to her in the result of the query.

Comment: @SimonR please read the comment above, if you could help me it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Check the table name within the where statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the following way. Thanks to all for the help.

```
SELECT consultant.name, consultant.surname FROM consultant 
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT id_project, participate.id_consultant FROM participate 
           INNER JOIN project 
           USING(id_project) 
           INNER JOIN client ON client.id = project.id_cliente 
                 WHERE client.name like 'Juan Perez'
          )
project ON project.id_consultant = consultant.id 
        WHERE project.id_project IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work if on the conditions of the join to client you exclude the client name there that it will return you what you want.

```
SELECT consultant.name, consultant.surname 
FROM consultor
INNER JOIN participate ON participate.id_consultant = consultant.id
INNER JOIN project ON  project.id = participate.id_project
INNER JOIN client ON  client.id = project.id_client and client.name NOT IN ("Juan Perez");
```